# Problema monedas JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este problema que resolver: Sabiendo esto, escribí una función `sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos`, que sume el valor de 5 monedas de 0.25 centavos y retorne el resultado.

Yo lo plantee de esta forma:

```
function sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos(){
       for( let i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){ 
           let totalMonedas = 0;
           return (totalMonedas = totalMonedas + 0.25);
       }
 }
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> La función `sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos` debe retornar 1.25

Quisiera saber en qué estoy mal.

Comment: y no es mejor `return 0.25 * 5` ??

Comment: Entiendo que la idea del ejercicio era que usaran el bucle, o por lo menos eso entendía yo con lo de "sume el valor de monedas". Lo que indicas tú es lo ideal, no cabe duda, y más si se crea una función genérica a la que se le pase el valor de la moneda y la cantidad.

Comment: Si. La idea era ir sumando. Por eso me pedia hacerlo de esa forma. Gracias por su colaboración.

Answer (score 7):

Tienes que declarar la variable totalMonedas fuera del bucle, si no cada vez que se ejecuta una iteración del mismo se reinicia el valor de totalMonedas a 0. Además el return debes hacerlo fuera del bucle, sino romperá el flujo en la primera iteración.

El código correcto sería el siguiente:

```js
function sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos(){
       let totalMonedas = 0;
       for( let i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){ 
          totalMonedas = totalMonedas + 0.25;
       }
       return totalMonedas;
 }
 console.log(sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos())
```

Answer (score 4):

Es que tienes mal definida la función, sería así:

```js
function sumar5(){
 let totalMonedas=0;
       for( let i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){ 
        totalMonedas = totalMonedas + 0.25;
     }
return totalMonedas;
 }
sumar5();
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Ahora si pude!!

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario. Si, esta respuesta fue la correcta y ya la marqué. Obvio que se podia hacer de otra forma pero esto era lo que me pedia mi actividad.

Answer (score 3):

El error está en que tienes el total de monedas (totalMonedas) dentro del for, lo que ocasiona que sea 0 en cada recorrido del ciclo y el resultado siempre sea 0.25, la solución es definir totalMonedas = 0 afuera del for.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón, el return también debe ir afuera

Comment: Si, gracias. Ya lo modifiqué

Answer (score 0):

Dado a que estás declarando total monedas dentro del array en 0 cada vez que entre se inicializa en 0, por eso debes declararla afuera:

```js
const sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos = () => {
    let totalMonedas = 0
    for( let i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){ 
        totalMonedas = totalMonedas + 0.25;
    }
    return totalMonedas
}

console.log(sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos())
```

texto en negrita

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es sacar el return del ciclo. Esto se debe a que provoca que este pare y retorne el valor, en este caso el for. Por lo que no llegaría al resultado deseado y solo realizaría una suma.

```js
function sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos(){
       let totalMonedas = 0;
       for( let i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){ 
          totalMonedas = totalMonedas + 0.25;
       }
       return totalMonedas;
 }
 console.log(sumar5MonedasDe25Centavos())
```